# error: no mixin named focus-border office ui fabric react.Issue when referring common

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

Requested priority: (Blocking, High, Normal, Low)  : High

Describe the issue:

I have created a sharepoint react framework solution.This solution uses List Component.I now want to use the (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/List/examples/List.Basic.Example.scss) in my solution.
@import '../../../common/common';

:global {
  .ms-ListBasicExample-itemCell {
    @include focus-border();

```
min-height: 54px;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-bottom: 1px solid $bodyDividerColor;
display: flex;
```

}

.ms-ListBasicExample-itemCell:hover {
    background: #EEE;
  }

.ms-ListBasicExample-itemImage {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }

.ms-ListBasicExample-itemContent {
    @include margin-left(10px);
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

.ms-ListBasicExample-itemName {
    @include ms-font-xl;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }

.ms-ListBasicExample-itemIndex {
    font-size: $ms-font-size-s;
    color: $ms-color-neutralTertiary;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

.ms-ListBasicExample-chevron {
    align-self: center;
    @include margin-left(10px);
    color: $ms-color-neutralTertiary;
    font-size: $ms-font-size-l;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
}
So i created a file called list.module.scss and copied the code above.
But it gives an error
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Office Fabric UI team has done a wonderful job, but they certainly didn't make the examples easy to use!

The ListBasicExample SCSS is a good example of this.

Here's how to get the example to work -- assuming that you are attempting to use the example inside of a React SPFx project:

1. Copy and paste the content of **List.Basic.Example.scss** into the SCSS that was created with your SCSS (e.g.: YourSolutionName.module.scss)
2. Find and remove the line that imports the **common.scss**

> @import '../../../common/common'; #REMOVE!

3. Make sure that at the top of your SCSS, you have the following line (add it if you don't have it):

> @import
>   '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';

4. From the SCSS you copied and pasted, find all the **@import** instructions and prefix all imports with **ms-**. For example, **@include focus-border();** will become

> @include ms-focus-border();

5. At the top of your SCSS, just below the **@import '~@Microsoft/sp-office-ui**...' paste the following line:

> $bodyDividerColor: "[theme:bodyDivider, default: #c8c8c8]";

And that should be it!

The mixins your example is looking for are already defined in the core Office Fabric UI scss -- they are just prefixed with **ms-**. The color that we add at the end is defined in another SCSS called **_semanticSlots.scss**; instead of importing the whole thing (and introduce more issues), I've just copied the definition.

I hope it helps?!

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply  ,  it worked but a change which is replaced line "@import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';" with @import '~office-ui-fabric-react/dist/sass/Fabric.scss'; .This is because as per microsoft best practices it is good to use css from React as both work differently.Correct me if i am wrong as this is a learning curve for everyone. and also not to forget to name the file as [filename].module.scss